# JavaScript table

Tags: javascript

I need help with this question:
I have created the table but I don't know how to use the event inside it

```html
<table style="width: 337px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 90px;" colspan="9">
        <table style="width: 329px;" border="1">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="width: 105.6875px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Skating</td>
              <td style="width: 110.3125px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Swimming</td>
              <td style="width: 130px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Cooking</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
      <td style="width: 90px;" colspan="9">
        <p>Hover Over Hobby Name to See Image</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<style>
  div {
    text-align: center;
  }
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
</style>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Something no-one seems to have bothered with is the red text and the cursor. By far the easiest way here would be to add some css. I'd consider adding the class 'hoverable' to the 3 tabs before adding a css class `.hoverable{cursor:pointer; text-color: red;}`

Comment: Thank youu @enhzflep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the idea...

```html
<table style="width: 337px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 90px;" colspan="9">
        <table style="width: 329px;" border="1">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="width: 105.6875px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Skating</td>
              <td style="width: 110.3125px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Swimming</td>
              <td style="width: 130px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Cooking</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
      <td style="width: 90px;" colspan="9">
        <p>Hover Over Hobby Name to See Image</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<style>
  div {
    text-align: center;
  }
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
</style>
```

```js
const hobies = document.querySelector('[hobies]')
const hoby_image = document.querySelector('[hoby-image]')

var hoby_images = {
   'Skating': 'https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300',
   'Swimming': 'https://picsum.photos/id/238/200/300',
   'Cooking': 'https://picsum.photos/id/239/200/300'
}

for(let i = 0; i < hobies.childElementCount; i++){
  hobies.children[i].addEventListener('mouseover', ()=>{
  
  hoby_image.children[0].src = `${Object.entries(hoby_images)[i][1]}`

  
  })
}
```

```css
td{
   cursor:pointer;
}
td:hover{
   border:red;
}
div {
    text-align: center;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
```

```html
<table style="width: 337px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 90px;" colspan="9">
        <table style="width: 329px;" border="1">
          <tbody>
            <tr hobies>
              <td style="width: 105.6875px;">Skating</td>
              <td style="width: 110.3125px;">Swimming</td>
              <td style="width: 130px;">Cooking</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
      <td hoby-image style="width: 90px;" colspan="9">
        <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300'></img>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, for each td tag you want to have the "mouseover" event, you need to add the event handler.

```
<tr class="hobbies">
    <td style="width: 105.6875px" onmouseover="changeImg('skating')">
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Skating
    </td>
    <td style="width: 110.3125px" onmouseover="changeImg('swimming')">
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Swimming
    </td>
    <td style="width: 130px" onmouseover="changeImg('cooking')">
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Cooking
    </td>
</tr>
```

For the style just use this

```
<style>
    div {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .hobbies td:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

Then at the second row change p tag with an img tag

```
<!-- Change the src attribute onmouseover -->
<img id="imgToChange" src="skating.jpg" alt="skating" />
```

At the bottom add this script

```
<script>
    const changeImg = (src) => {
        let img = document.getElementById("imgToChange");
        switch (src) {
            case "skating":
                img.src = "skating.jpg";
                img.alt = "skating";
                break;
            case "swimming":
                img.src = "swimming.jpg";
                img.alt = "swimming";
                break;
            case "cooking":
                img.src = "cooking.jpg";
                img.alt = "cooking";
        }
    };
</script>
```

Base on which td tag is hovering, you can set the src and alt attribute of img tag with parameter.

```js
const changeImg = (src) => {
    let img = document.getElementById("imgToChange");
    switch (src) {
      case "skating":
        img.src = "skating.jpg";
        img.alt = "skating";
        break;
      case "swimming":
        img.src = "swimming.jpg";
        img.alt = "swimming";
        break;
      case "cooking":
        img.src = "cooking.jpg";
        img.alt = "cooking";
    }
  };
```

```css
div {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .hobbies td:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: red;
  }
```

```html
<table style="width: 337px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 90px" colspan="9">
        <table style="width: 329px" border="1">
          <tbody>
        <tr class="hobbies">
        <td style="width: 105.6875px" onmouseover="changeImg('skating')">
            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Skating
        </td>
        <td style="width: 110.3125px" onmouseover="changeImg('swimming')">
            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Swimming
        </td>
        <td style="width: 130px" onmouseover="changeImg('cooking')">
            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Cooking
        </td>
    </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="text-align: center">
      <td style="width: 90px" colspan="9">
        <!-- Change the src attribute onmouseover -->
        <img id="imgToChange" src="skating.jpg" alt="skating" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />
```

Comment: Thank youuu @baolhq

Comment: hope it help 

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use tables to do the layout (1992 called and wants a word with you) I've re-written using divs, but the concepts are exactly the same.

Attach the event handler `.addEventListener` for the *mouseover* event — you would attach it to your `<td...>` elements instead of my `<li>` elements.

I have attached which image to use to the element being hovered using a `data-` attribute, so the handler just gets that value and doesn't have to figure out which of the items is being hovered.

```js
const imageHolder = document.querySelector('#imageholder img');
const hobbies = document.querySelectorAll('#hobbies li');
hobbies.forEach(el =>
  el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
    const hobbyImage = e.target.dataset.image;
    imageHolder.src = `https://picsum.photos${hobbyImage}`;
  })
);
```

```css
#app {
  width: 80%;
}
#imageholder {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
ul#hobbies {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
}
li + li {
  border-left: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <ul id="hobbies">
    <li data-image="/300/200">Skating</li>
    <li data-image="/300/201">Swimming</li>
    <li data-image="/300/202">Cooking</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="imageholder">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank youuu @Stephen P